# How do I decide which appenders act on a log with `clojure.tools.logging`?

Tags: logging, clojure, logback

In my `project.clj` `:dependencies`, I have:

```
[org.clojure/tools.logging "0.2.6"]
[ch.qos.logback/logback-classic "1.0.11"]
[net.logstash.logback/logstash-logback-encoder "1.0"]
```

In my `core.clj`, I have:

```
(clojure.tools.logging/info "both stdout and stash")
(clojure.tools.logging/log "stash" :info nil "only stash?")
```

On my resource path, I have a file `logback.xml`, in which I define two appenders `stdout` and `stash` both attached to root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">

  <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="stash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>example.log</file>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
  </appender>

  <root level="all">
    <appender-ref ref="stash" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

When I run my program, I see the following (desired) output in `example.log`:

```
{"@timestamp":"2013-04-10T12:42:16-04:00","@message":"both stdout and stash","@fields":{"logger_name":"scheduler.core","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}}
{"@timestamp":"2013-04-10T12:42:16-04:00","@message":"only stash?","@fields":{"logger_name":"stash","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}}
```

However, I see both of the following lines printed to stdout -- I only wanted to see the first:

```
12:42:16.573 [main] INFO  scheduler.core - both stdout and stash
12:42:16.641 [main] INFO  stash - only stash?
```

How do I select which appender to log to with `clojure.tools.logging`?  Specifically, with both `stdout` and `stash` attached at root, how can I log only to `stash`?

Comment: Define a logger with the name="clojure.tools.logging"

Comment: That would then apply only to messages sent from the `clojure.tools.namespace`, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logback applies all active appenders that match not just the first one so your root level will apply to all messages.
take the `<appender-ref ref="stdout" />` out of the root level and add a logger specifically to use it.

```
 <logger name="project.core" level="INFO"> 
    <appender-ref ref="stash" /> 
  </logger>

 <root level="ERROR"> 
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
  </root>
```

Comment: How do I "match" an appender.  If I take stdout out of the root level, I will not see either message.  How can I match only stdout, only stash, or both?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to clarify for you:

The configuration of what gets logged where is entirely controlled by your logging implementation (logback in this case).

All `clojure.tools.logging` messages use a logging namespace. By default, the value used is the clojure namespace from which the logging call is invoked; this is analogous to how in Java you might pass the current class to the logger factory.

This logging namespace is used by most logging implementations to allow you to set logging configuration at the namespace level.

As to your questions:

**How do I select which appender to log to with `clojure.tools.logging`?**

Do it exactly how you would do it when logging from Java, either globally, or specific to some package/class/namespace.

**Specifically, with both `stdout` and `stash` attached at root, how can I log only to `stash`?**

In logback, the name of the appender has no bearing on log message namespace.  If you want to configure namespace-specific logging, you can do something like the following:

```
<appender name="foo">...</appender>
<appender name="bar">...</appender>

<root level="WARN">
  <appender-ref ref="foo" />
</root>

<logger name="myproject.core" level="DEBUG">
  <appender-ref ref="bar" />
</logger>
```

In the above, every `WARN` (or higher) message in any namespace will be sent to the `foo` appender, and every `DEBUG` (or higher) message from `myproject.core` namespace will be sent to the `bar` appender.

Comment: Thanks for the clean explanation.  Until Arthur Ulfeldts's edit, I was missing the existence of loggers separate from appenders, which gives the desired solution.